# Sharpness of multiplicity function

Tags: statistical-mechanics

This is quoted from Daniel Schroeder's *An introduction to thermal Physics*:

> $$\Omega= \left(\frac{e}{N}\right)^{2N} \; e^{N\ln (q/2)^2} e^{-N(2x/q)^2}\;=\; \Omega_\text{max} \cdot e^{-N(2x/q)^2}\;. $$
>
> A function of this form is called **Gaussian**; it has a peak at $x=0$ and a sharp fall-off on either side. The multiplicity falls off to $1/e$ of its maximum value when $$N\left(\frac{2x}{q}\right)^2= 1\;\; \text{or} \;\; x= \frac{q}{2\sqrt N}\;.$$

[image]

> ***This is actually a rather large number. But if $N= 10^{20},$ it's only one part in ten billion of the entire scale of the graph! On the scale used in the figure, where the width of the peak is about $1~\text{cm},$ the full scale of the graph would have to stretch $10^{10}~\text{cm}$ - more than twice around the earth. And near the edge of the page, where $x$ is only ten times larger than $q/2\sqrt N$, the multiplicity is less than its maximum value by a factor $e^{-100}\approx 10^{-44}\;.$***

I've not really understood what he is talking in the bold lines above especially the phrase used here, ***one part in ten billion of entire scale of the graph.***

Could anyone please explain what he is actually intending to say in those lines?

Comment: I there a typo in your first equation?

Comment: Where? Well...Let me check, sir.

Comment: You have an exponent in the exponent. I think that's a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The concept the paragraph is trying to drive home is that although the absolute size of the Gaussian peak is very large, it's small when compared to the length of the graph. Since $q$ is going to be of comparable size to $N$, the total scale of the Gaussian will be about $N$ while the peak will cover $\sqrt{N}$.

So if you were to look at a case where $N=100$, then if the peak were scaled to $1$cm the entire graph of microstates would only span $10$cm. In that case the peak would be a full ten percent of the entire graph. In absolute terms the peak would only cover $10$ units, but in relative terms the peak covers $10\%$ of the graph.

But in statistical mechanics we're interested in large numbers like $N=10^{20}$. In that case, when the Gaussian peak is scaled to $1$cm the entire graph would cover $10^{10}$cm. The absolute size of the peak is now much much larger and covers $10^{10}$ units, but the peak now only spans $.00000001\%$ or one part in ten billion of the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; could you tell what you meant by the _length_ of the graph? I would appreciate if you could post some pics for visualisation.

Comment: Please respond when you come.